# jQuery keyup triggered when tabbing to page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

I'm trying to create a live search on my site using jQuery and ajax.

However, if the search box has focus, and I move to another browser tab, jQuery triggers the `keyup()` function when I come back to the search page.

I've mocked this up in [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/USsdU/)

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Open the JSfiddle and any other browser tab
2. Give the text box focus
3. Move to another browser tab
4. Go back to the original page (the JSfiddle)

**Expected/intended:** `keyup()` isn't triggered

**What happens:** `keyup()` triggered, as shown by timestamp

I don't know much about Javascript and I've read the jQuery documentation, but I can't come up with an answer.

Is this happening because I'm doing something wrong?
Is it a Javascript/jQuery or browser issue? (Using Chrome)
How might I prevent it happening?

Thanks! Be gentle.

**UPDATE**

It appears it is only triggered if using Ctrl+Tab, rather than just clicking between tabs. Can be replicated by clicking away from the page, but Ctrl+Shift+Tab to get back to search page.

I would suppose the solution is as mentioned below, to return keyCode 9 as `false`, but will leave it open for other suggestions.

Comment: im useing chrome too and can't reproduce it

Comment: Does the text box have focus before you tab away? That's a shame, I hoped I'd done all I could to help!

Comment: This is ok, but why do you need to filter such events? Just read input's value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using chrome (on win7). Cannot reproduce.
One solution for you though, would be to check which keycode (`e.keyCode`) is being generated, and `return false` if it's always the same one.
For ex, if the keyCode is 37:

```
$('#search').keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 37) return false;
    $('#test').append('<li>'+e.timeStamp+'</li>');
});
​
```

Comment: this would of course eliminate that key from your keyup function, so you'd need to be sure you don't want to test for that specific key.

Comment: I'm also able to replicate it in Safari. Interestingly, the keyCode is 9 which is tab.

Comment: E.g.: `Ctrl+V` also generates a `keyup` event. I'm not sure, filtering is really required.